# Shift the pendulum?

Tags: idioms

I came across the idiom "shift the pendulum" or "a swing of the pendulum". I suppose the idiom means a **major change** but I can't understand the point because when you shift the pendulum from the central line, it starts swinging and then gradually stops. There's no major change. Maybe it means to motivate or to start a move. Please help me understand this idiom.

Comment: Who knows, without having the exact context.

Comment: The pendulum is a pretty well established metaphor, but I don't really know what "shift the pendulum" means without any context.

Comment: @pazzo - I don't think "exact context" is needed in this case. A _pendulum shift_ can occur in economics, politics, or sports, and they all pretty much mean the same thing: Things were going pretty good (or bad) for a while, and now they seem headed in the other direction (or heading back to normal).

Answer (score 3):

It is more common to say the pendulum *is swinging* (or *has swung*).

To say this means that thought, practice or political leanings (for instance) have *shifted* in one direction, but it is expected that at some future time they will swing back —because they have in the past.

An example is educational theory with regard to *phonics*. For some years, schools will try to teach spelling without teaching phonics, but they inevitably revert to teaching phonics.

As these swings can take years, the metaphor assumes the decay of the amplitude of swing to be negligible.

Comment: This phrase can also be used to say that things may have gone too far in one particular direction, and now they are heading back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is meant is a paradigm shift. To change how we see the world. A pendulum swings from one side to the other. Using a pendulum in a political reference is almost like using a tennis match with the ball being hit back and forth. But the pendulum never wins. There are no sides. Not like his side and her side. Red or blue. Just this side and that side. Politically, makes no sense.
A paradigm is a like person's glasses. That person shapes their glasses through teaching, unique life experiences. 
To use a paradigm shift in a political reference would make more sense. We, as a people, need to change how we view the world. Teach our children how to look at people of another, race, creed, sex, religion....

Answer (score 0):

The idiom refers to the inevitable return of the pendulum to center or rest, in doing so it moves past center in the other direction, only briefly reaching center or the point of rest. A "Pendulum Swing" refers to the typically equal but opposite reaction to some event, organization, political party etc.

For example, when a particular political party in office performs poorly in the eyes of the voters, the "Pendulum Swing" represents the voters moving in the opposite direction in the next election in an attempt to regain center or rest in the condition of their country. The challenge is that the pendulum does not just return to center and stop, because of momentum, and the natural inclination to over correct, it continues the other direction until once again, it stops and goes back and so on.

A further example of this was the 1976 Presidential election of a little known Georgia farmer named Jimmy Carter. 1972 President elect Richard Nixon, had resigned and left office ahead of impeachment.  The resulting scandal caused such mistrust in the American voter with the Republican Party, that when Gerald Ford who assumed the Presidency after Nixon's exit chose not to run, Americans elected a Democratic Governor from Georgia who had little recognition on  a national stage.

Answer (score 0):

A pendulum swings back and forth, from far to the left to far to the right, from one extreme to the other.

In the same way, social forces and popular beliefs sometimes swing back and forth. One generation is conservative. The next generation is liberal. Then the next generation is conservative. Etc.

The "pendulum theory" is based on the idea that some ideology or belief system is adopted and put into effect with high hopes, the people who do it are convinced that this will create a new age of peace, prosperity, freedom, whatever. But in practice there are always flaws. So some time later people see the flaws and failures and reject the basic ideology. And so they try some opposite extreme, thinking THIS is the real answer. But of course that turns out to be less than perfect also. So people react against that, they now see the advantages of the previous system, and society goes in the opposite direction. And so it swings back and forth, like a pendulum.

For example, America in the 1920s embraced free market capitalism. For a while it seemed like things were going great. The economy was booming, there were plenty of jobs, the stock market was going up and up, etc. Then in the 1930s the Great Depression hit. Many blamed it -- rightly or wrongly, I don't want to get into that here -- on flaws in capitalism. And so the country turned to socialism. Many socialist programs were enacted, government expanded, etc. While there were many programs to help the poor, the economy didn't really recover. Plus in World War 2 people saw really bad examples of government-controlled economies in Nazi Germany and Soviet Russia. So in the 1950s people turned back to capitalism. In the 1970s the country turned to a more middle ground. In the 1980s back to the right. In the 1990s more to the middle. In the 2000s kind of muddled. In the 2010s sharply left. The pendulum swings back and forth.

I'm sure people will disagree with some of my characterizations above. But that's how at least some people see it. That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'pendulum' is philosophical and metaphorical. A swing of pendulum means a major change that occurs in life. today you are happy, tomorrow you are sad - that is a change.