# momentum-swinging -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([Ukraine rebels deny internal strife behind commander's slaying](http://news.yahoo.com/ukraine-rebels-deny-internal-strife-behind-commanders-slaying-222518764.html)):

> Mozgovoi played a central role in **momentum-swinging** battles that forced pro-Western President Petro Poroshenko to sue for peace on two occasions.

This is obviously not a real adjective in English—an ad-hoc one, if you will, to add idiomatism to the sentence. But what do you think it actually means?

Comment: IMHO, I think it means about the same thing as [pendulum shift](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/56515/3281) mentioned in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a ***compound adjective***. In English, this an adjective constructed with 2 or more words.

The meaning of momentum-swinging in this context, means a particular turning point in the battle. The phrase 'momentum-swinging battles' conveys that before, one group in the battle had the upper hand, but now, the other group are more powerful.

Think of it like, the momentum/power, which was firstly with Petro Poroshenko, has now been transferred to Mozgovio, and now he has the upper hand. Overall, the phrase shows how these battles were vital, and how the power has shifted, (i.e. the momentum has swung from one side to the other).

Answer (score 1):

"momentum-swinging" is a fairly recent *coinage* based *roughly* on this pattern:

**birds that eat seeds -> *seed-eating birds***

I say "roughly" because it is the momentum that swings:

`momentum swings (intransitive)`

so that "to swing the momentum" means "to cause the momentum to swing".